# In publish application doesn't work but in local work fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
$("#SItemDetailsContainer").load(loc[loc.length - 1].includes("/")
    ? loc + 'ItemDetails/Conditiion_Partial?SelectedItem=' + SelectedItem + '&SelectedName=' + Selectedname + '&SelectedID=' + Selectedid + '&SelectedNO=' + Selectedno
    : loc + 'ItemDetails/Conditiion_Partial?SelectedItem=' + SelectedItem + '&SelectedName=' + Selectedname + '&SelectedID=' + Selectedid + '&SelectedNO=' + Selectedno, function (response, status, xhr)
{
    if (status == "error") {
        alert(response.responseText)
    }
    else if (status == "success") {
        $("#txtItem").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#txtName").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#txtID").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#txtNO").prop("disabled", false);
    }
```

Above code always get error when using publish application but in local it's working don't know what's problem in code.

Comment: A bit hard to say without the error. But the issue is probably in `loc ` which is probably a location. which is different on the published environment.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan in alert responseText it's display undefined. and location is correct

Comment: @Rafalon it's partial class.

Comment: @Rafalon two **i** ?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't really matter, what bothers me now is that you use `?:` (ternary operator) for  no purpose at all: you load the same thing whether `loc[loc.length - 1].includes("/")` or not. I guess you miss a `/` at the beginning of your second line (`"/ItemDetails..."`)

Comment: `[loc.length - 1].includes("/")` part removed and check still same issue. i will check `/` issue.

Comment: @Rafalon thank you very much. there was `/` missing in second line. now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that a minor fix would be to add a "`/`" as such:

```
$("#SItemDetailsContainer").load(loc[loc.length - 1].includes("/")
    ? loc + 'ItemDetails/Conditiion_Partial?SelectedItem=' + SelectedItem + '&SelectedName=' + Selectedname + '&SelectedID=' + Selectedid + '&SelectedNO=' + Selectedno
    : loc + '/ItemDetails/Conditiion_Partial?SelectedItem=' + SelectedItem + '&SelectedName=' + Selectedname + '&SelectedID=' + Selectedid + '&SelectedNO=' + Selectedno, function (response, status, xhr)
{
    ...
}
```

But you could also do (add a `/` only if it is needed):

```
$("#SItemDetailsContainer").load(loc + (loc[loc.length - 1].includes("/") ? "" : "/")
    + 'ItemDetails/Conditiion_Partial?SelectedItem=' + SelectedItem + '&SelectedName=' + Selectedname + '&SelectedID=' + Selectedid + '&SelectedNO=' + Selectedno, function (response, status, xhr)
{
    ...
}

// The point here is that you have your location:
loc
// to which you add a slash if needed
// (which means only if the location doesn't end with a slash):
+ (loc[loc.length - 1].includes("/") ? "" : "/")
// to which you add the location you want to reach:
+ "ItemDetails/..."
```

Comment: But you could also do (add a / only if it is needed): it's not working for me.

Comment: Did you try with my latest edit? I initially wrote `? "/" : ""` but it should be `? "" : "/"`

Comment: I was try your first code and it's working fine but 2nd one is not working for me.

Comment: You probably have a typo somewhere (be sure to have a `+` and not a `?` or a `:` on the line `+ 'ItemDetails…` for example)